# Distinguish between local cache callback and server reached callback in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, listener

I was building a chat application in Android using Firebase. When we use Firestore SDK, it triggers any listeners on updates as soon as data is written into local Firestore cache. Since I have included server-time in the field, a second trigger will occur when the data has actually reached server, since server-time gets updated there. Is there a possible way for me to distinguish between these two triggers, so that, I can update the user that the message reached the server (like WhatsApp).

If this is absolutely not possible, I have two options:

1. Use custom cloud functions to send the message, so that listener triggers only after data has reached the server. Until then, I can show pending status for user.
2. Use custom cloud functions that triggers on Firestore writes at that location, and sets a flag, which indicates the data has reached the server.

If I have choose, which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine whether a snapshot is guaranteed to be up-to-date with the server by checking the `isFromCache()` and `hasPendingWrites()` methods in its [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata).

Comment: Is the same possible with `realtime database`?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but that's make a great [feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report). 